# Adobe Audition, Songr problems with Wine

Tags: wine

Hi i am joying ubuntu world recently, i know it since 2014 i always used the live usb or cd, never installed.

Gotta be honest I always being a windows user, but i passed in ubuntu coz windows lately had many bugs and many problems, so i decided to pass definitively to ubuntu.... a part this I have  little a problem with it.. I configure it correctly but  some programs are not working as i would like.

Those are program used in windows adobe audition and songr, i searched many site for them, but all of them said that it's not possible to use em, I badly need that programs, I do not wanna install windows just for using this two programs, is there a way to let em work?

I tried wine but they don't... It only work with wine winamp and trackor.

Asap thanks for your help

Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

Before you want to install Window Application to run with Wine, you should check the application at [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php). You can download and install [Adobe Audition](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25911) with Wine. But Songr is not support on Wine. You should find alternative app.